# meaning of "mask out" in screen printing

Tags: meaning, translation

I'm having a hard time translating a passage about screen printing.

> For screen prints, mesh (originally silk) is stretched tautly across a
>   frame. An image is glued or otherwise affixed onto the mesh to *mask*
>   *out* compositional areas...
>   Areas *masked out* by compositional shapes are nonporous and obstruct
>   the ink through the mesh.

I looked up the dictionary and it says the phrase *to mask out* means "to conceal or cover part of something from view." So do the verb "*mask*" and the phrase "*mask out*" mean the same? 
I searched every website related to screen printing to figure out the basic concept of screen printing, but I don't still get it. And a friend of mine told me that since the particle *out* is after *mask*, *mask out* means "to cover *except* the compositional area." Is he correct?

For example, if I want to get a star print on my t-shirt using screen printing, how can I get the star-shaped print by masking out the compositional area(=a star shape)?
Maybe in here "the compositional area" does not indicate the image(the star) itself, but the background area except the star shape? I'm getting confused..
Or *mask out* means "to mask *except* the star shape"?
I want to understand the meaning of *mask out* and compositional areas (Are they shapes or backgrounds?) more clearly. 
Thanks...

Comment: Yes. More on masks: http://www.kuroda-electric.eu/screen-mask

Comment: A mask covers (overlays) a pattern on the select area. It does not cover the whole of the "star" completely, in the OP's example, but small discrete areas spread across the area under the star.

Comment: @Kris Thanks Kris. I'd already checked out the website that you provided me, but it was quite difficult to understand the process. So here _mask out_ means not just covering, but overlaying? I'm not sure what  your _yes_ in your post answers for. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Your quote uses *mask out* in two different ways. Technically, you *mask out* everything but the compositional areas, which are the areas that you want to get printed.

Answer (score 1):

Conventional silk screening is done by somehow placing a pattern on a piece of silk (or silk-like synthetic cloth) in a rectangular frame, laying the frame over the surface to be printed, and forcing paint through the silk (with a sort of squeegee).  The pattern is achieved by making portions of the silk non-porous, so the paint does not pass through.

"Masking" is the process of making the silk non-porous in spots.  It may be done using a photographic process, the mask may be painted on by hand (often using liquid wax), or (simplest) pieces of paper may be stuck to the back of the silk to serve as the mask.  If you want to print, eg, a single star, you would mask everywhere *except* where the star appears -- ie, the mask might be a large sheet of paper with a star-shaped hole in the middle.

An area that has been rendered non-porous by the masking process has been "masked off" or "masked out" -- there is no difference between the two terms.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of masking out is explained in the passage, so I presume your query is about which part is masked out—the shape attached, or the remainder.

Again, the passage explains that the attached piece "obstucts" the ink; that is, it cannot pass through in that area.

This is similar to **masking off** areas you DON'T want to paint on, e.g., a car or a house.
http://www.google.com/search?q=mask+off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=tCIRVfiLDpD8oQS-jYGQAw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=320&bih=356#tbm=isch&q=paint+%2B+%22masking+off%22

Comment: So for example, If I want to pain the door, not a doorknob, I have to _mask off_ the doorknob that so that it remains clean, right? But I guess the proecess of screen printing in the passage is opposite to _masking out_ since the areas or prints that you want to get are pressed onto your t-shirt with color. So you mask off not to get it colored, but according to the passge, the compositional areas should not be masked off because the ink needs to pass through them...I don't know...

Comment: You are correct about painting. I am not as familiar with silkscreen, but this video should clarify.  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4GYNYcTJWlA